# Can rocky hills similar to the Scottish highlands be located next to a bog?

Tags: science-based, earth-like, geography, geology, weather

I've written about these rocky hills with short grass, gravel, shrubs, and big boulders. At the bottom of one of the hills is a big bog. Basically I've designed some buildings to be sticking out of the hill and half-suspended over the bog with stilts, which spreads into a bigger marketplace all on top of the bog all on stilts.

I'm just concerned that a hill next to a bog would likely be more damp and green than the one I've designed, which is more rocky.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you been to Scotland!? It's all mountain, beach or bog! :p

Comment: I can only speak anecdotally and not scientifically, but I recall going up the [sgurr](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_jVcOg_5E02U/TCUjZW2uRBI/AAAAAAAACwE/Ck-PvTeDEK8/s1600/an+sgurr.jpg) and our trek there seemed almost entirely bog!

Comment: As an experienced Scottish hill walker and mountaineer, this question astounds me. Scotland is a bog. It rains 250 days a year. The ground never dries. It's truly hell on earth to the unacquainted.

Comment: Dartmoor features rocky outcrops (tors) and extensive bogs.

Comment: I've sunk up to my waist in a bog near the top of Helvellyn, luckily it was just one leg. Said bog was near (East of) Red Tarn, if you want to look at the area

Comment: @Liath Scotland has beaches?

Answer (score 18):

So long as the design of the bog area allows:

1. high water run-off from the hills,
2. is a shallow dirt-and-biomatter-filled basin that collects the water and
3. enough erosion has taken place to fill that shallow basin with fertile soil.

Then yup, I've no problem with this.

And the proof in the pudding are the [blanket bogs of the Scottish uplands](https://www.nature.scot/landscapes-and-habitats/habitat-types/mountains-heaths-and-bogs/blanket-bog).  They're even showing [wear and tear due to global warming](https://www.scotsman.com/news/environment/highland-bog-reveals-global-warming-threat-to-peatlands-1-4173758).  Best of all, the [highlands are traditionally rocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_of_Scotland#Highlands_and_Islands), so go right ahead and have a bog next to your rocky hill!

Comment: Oh YEAH that sounds great! Thanks for the reference that's uber helpful!

Comment: Don't forget Kinder Scout

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that bogs can actually from on slopes if the earth is rocky/saturated enough

Comment: A bog is mostly peat, which forms from the mosses that grow there and a little nutrient poor soil, nutrient rich soils are more likely to be found in a marsh or other type of wetland.https://knowledgenuts.com/2013/12/02/difference-between-a-marsh-a-swamp-a-bog-and-a-fen/

Comment: @Separatrix But Kinder Scout isn't anything like that.  The OP is looking for a grassy/gravelly/stony mountain, but if anything, Kinder itself is even more boggy than its surroundings.  Also the peat bog there is typically bone-dry in summer.  Scotland is much more like the OP's question, particularly places like Rannoch Moor.

Comment: @Graham, Kinder Scout is fundamentally millstone grit, apart from the bog on top. Admittedly that's not where the OP wants the bog, but it's another example of rocky and boggy not being exclusive.

Comment: @Separatrix Fair point.  The main requirement, as JBH says, is something that holds onto the water.  Kinder is in the unusual situation of having a basin on top of the hill.